# How one can install sagemath on Ubuntu?

Tags: sagemath

I tried to install sagemath via command line but encountered a problem. Am I doing something wrong? I have Ubuntu 13.10.

```
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp7y1mxl/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp7y1mxl/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key BE796FF2 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp7y1mxl/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key BE796FF2: public key "Launchpad PPA for AIMS" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease                       
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                   
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                             
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg                   
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release                         
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy Release                                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                  
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Sources                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Sources                                
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Sources                        
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Sources                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main i386 Packages                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg                      
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted i386 Packages                
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release                
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en               
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Sources                     
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Sources          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US            
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Sources              
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Sources                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en               
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Sources               
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Sources                 
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en             
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Sources               
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Sources
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en           
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ sudo apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sagemath-upstream-binary is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sagemath-upstream-binary' has no installation candidate
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only saw this  post now but the PPA doesn't seem to work, I just downloaded the latest  binary version of Sage Math 6.1.1 and installed it for all users(only me) on my computer using symbolic link. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. Perhaps you can use the cloud version.

http://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html

and the help file

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/installation/binary.html#linux-and-os-x

Answer (score 5):

I managed to install it on an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit fresh install from the PPA. However, I replaced apt-get by aptitude. That is,

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

I wonder wheter the trick was a) 14.04 instead of 13.10, b) 64 bit (amd64) instead of 32 bit (i386), c) aptitude instead of apt-get or d) time healing all wounds.

Comment: As of now, the PPA has an amd64 version but not a i386 version of sagemath-upstream-binary. So, I suspect the answer to your question is (b).

Comment: This PPA is no longer maintained.