# Sagemath in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, sagemath

I wanted to know if there is any way to install Sagemath in Ubuntu 17.10.
I haven't found the install package, but I just wanted to check if it was just me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just you.

For Ubuntu 17.10, (artful aardvark) there doesn't appear to be a way of installing using the package repositories. As you can see from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/sagemath

> There is no current release of this source package in The Artful Aardvark. You can still report bugs, make translations, and so on, but they might not be used until the package is published.

I'm not entirely sure about the reason, but it appears that they had difficulties with upgrading sagemath from version `7.4` (the version that *was* present in zesty (17.04), to `8.1` (the version that would have been present in artful), possibly due to dependency issues. It appears that they're trying to get it into 18.04. See these links for some more details:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sagemath/+question/660257

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sagemath/+changelog#detail_sagemath_8.0-8.1~build1

https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/24084

#### PPA

The traditionally recommended [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath) (say [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931037/failing-to-install-sagemath-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409372/how-one-can-install-sagemath-on-ubuntu#599191)) also won't work as they state that:

> UPDATE 2017: Sagemath is now in Debian and there is no longer a need to maintain this PPA.

which is true, except that in this case Ubuntu doesn't perfectly follow Debian...

#### How to install, then?

You can usually download sagemath binaries from sagemath.org itself, instead. Some installation details are [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html#linux-and-os-x) and the Linux binaries are available via a mirror [here](https://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html).

If you go to the above binary download link you will (in turn) be prompted to choose a mirror close to you (to speed up downloading), your processor architecture (probably 64-bit if you're unsure) and then your operating system. The last step is tricky, since Ubuntu 17.10 is not actually one of the options. However, selecting the Ubuntu 16.04 option or the latest Debian one *might* work (I have no access to an Ubuntu 17.10 system, so I haven't tested this)...

If that doesn't work, then complain at the [bug tracker](https://trac.sagemath.org/) or [build from source](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/source.html).